# Run sequel of run configurations in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I work on web applications with eclipse which means each time I modify server side code I have to run maven clean install then start my server again. I have run configurations for these both steps in eclipse but need to wait for the first one to finish before starting the second one.

I have also other cases when I need to run maven clean install on 5 or 6 projects in a given order after having updated all of them.

So my question is: does anybody know **how to define sequels of runs and run them in the right order on one click in Eclipse** (i'm using Indigo). I didn't found any plugin nor help on my favorite search engine.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an Ant-script which wraps the Maven commands ([with using Maven Ant Tasks](http://maven.apache.org/ant-tasks/index.html)) in the correct order. Then you can create a launch configuration for that Ant script in Eclipse.

Or just write a shell script and create an launch configuration for that in Eclipse.